# Bootstrap Drop Down - Use Caret As A Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the Bootstrap 3.0 dropdown menu and it works fine. At present when I hover over the text or the caret next to it, it displays the menu. However I wish to alter it so that only when I hover over the caret does it displays the dropdown.

My code is as follows:

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a href='register'>Register Account</a>
         <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a>Bookmark</a></li>
            <li >Close</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

My css code is:

```
li.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle {
    display:inline-block;
}

a.dropdown-toggle:hover{
    display: block;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "Register Account" text from the `a` tag so that only the caret is within the link:

```html
<li class="dropdown">
    Register Account
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    ...
</li>
```

You'll then need to add in a bit of CSS to keep the caret in line with the text:

```css
li.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried that but am having trouble getting it to show the menu upon hover.